# Difference between behavior of fork/join nodes toward tokens with other nodes of Activity diagrams

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

As [Thomas Kilian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379653/thomas-kilian) described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52165108/1043882), normal behavior of nodes of Activity diagrams with tokens is:

> A node becomes active when at all of its incoming `InformationFlow connectors` a token has arrived. When the node finalizes it sends single tokens along all its outgoing InformationFlow connectors.

But also he added:

> There are special nodes like fork and merge which behave a bit different

I know that behavior of "merge" node differs because it becomes immediately active by receiving first token and accepts one among several alternate flows. But what is the difference between behavior of fork/join nodes with tokens with normal behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Merge`- and `DecisionNode`s look the same, but are different elements: [image].

In a diagram you can only distinguish both by looking at the incoming and outgoing `InformationFlow`s. The first has multiple incoming and one outgoing while the second has the opposite relation. A `MergeNode` accepts any incoming token and forwards it directly to its single outgoing `InformationFlow`. So unlike `Action`s it will not wait for all tokens. The `DecisionNode` in contrast accepts only a single token and lets it pass to only one of its outgoing `InformationFlow`s. It is the modeler's responsibility to set guards in a way that only one evaluates to true. If there are more (or even unguarded) `InformationFlow`s the token will take any arbitrary free route.

`Fork` and `Join` are also two different elements which look the same: [image] (or vertically).

You can also distinguish them by the number of in-/outgoing `InformationFlow`s. `Fork` has one in and multiple out and `Join` vice versa. A `Fork` will send as many tokens as it has outgoing `InformationFlow`s once a token arrives at its single incoming `InformationFlow`. The `Join` will (like `Action`s) wait for tokens arrive at all of its incoming `InformationFlow`s. Only then it will emerge a single token at its single outgoing `InformationFlow`.

So while `Merge`- and `DecisionNode`s control the flow of a single token (execution path) `Fork` and `Join` are used to start and synchronize parallel execution paths.

Comment: I'm agree with "It is the modeler's responsibility to set guards in a way that only one evaluates to true". But will a token take any arbitrary free route, If there are more (or even unguarded) InformationFlows? Or in this case "Activity fails"? Also I think there is no real case which needs to a `decision` node without `guard`. Do I think true?

Comment: No. See p. 388: _If multiple targets accept the token simultaneously, then the token traverses only one of the edges corresponding to the accepting targets, but which one is not determined by this specification._