# multiple tokens from single branch before joining

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

Below I have a `join` node which synchronize branches `A` and `B`:

```
         |
-----A-->|
         |
         |-->action-->
         |
-----B-->|
         |
```

I know `join` waits until receiving tokens from both `A` and `B`, but what will happen in this situation:

Tokens `a1` and `a2` receive from branch `A` before `b1` which is a token from `B`?

- Does `a2` override `a1`?
- Does `join` synchronize `a1` and `b1` and `a2` must wait for `b2` to be accepted?

Comment: Your second bullet is correct.

Comment: @JimL. An answer is not a comment ;-)

Comment: I know, but I’m on my mobile phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like Tetris if you turn your picture 90 degrees clock wise. Tokens from `A` and `B` pile up at each `ControlFlow`. If **all** ingoing flows have one token the `Join` takes them (the lowest Tetris layer) away and emits a single one (your Tetris score :-). The other tokens fall down one layer and the game repeats.

See also my explanation at [Difference between behavior of fork/join nodes toward tokens with other nodes of Activity diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181253/difference-between-behavior-of-fork-join-nodes-toward-tokens-with-other-nodes-of)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation; but do you remember where this is said in specification?

Comment: Read pp. 387 of UML 2.5

Comment: I asked another question in about `UML`: "When a token which is created by JoinNode, will be rejected?" here:https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/379265/174635. Can you see that please?

Comment: The current answer seems pretty decent.